# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 start up problems

Tags: command-line, apt

I have Windows 7. I tried to install Ubuntu and the installation was almost over when an error message popped up and the installation failed. Then I rebooted the computer but the computer wont start. A blank screen appeared and nothing is happening. The same thing is happening every time I am starting my computer. How can I solve it? Please help.

Comment: Can U be more specific on how did U install Ubuntu .. next to Windows so that U can do a dual boot with windows ,did U delete Windows and installed Ubuntu only ?? Another thing what architecture did U used 32 bit or 64 ,why I'm asking ?? because if U have a Cpu with a 64-bit architecture and U installed an os for 32-bit it's ok , if instead U have a 32-bit Cpu and U installed a 64 is obvious why doesn't work .However could be even because U made in a wrong way the partitions .Just give me a bit more details about how did you install Ubuntu ,help me so I can help U .

Answer (score 0):

Try to hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during PC boot and see if a boot menu appears

**or**

try to use the [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) program from a LiveCD-USB of Ubuntu to repair the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, the easiest thing is probably to install Ubuntu again.  If it fails a second time, make a note of the exact error message so you can put it in a question. As it is now, there's not too much anyone can say to help you as you haven't given sufficient information.

Answer (score 0):

To fix grub boot loder follow this guide.

You need Ubuntu 12.04 livecd for repairing grub boot loader . Here assuming the Ubuntu partition is sda7. Boot up ubuntu from the livecd,open terminal and run:

```
sudo -i and see what is your linux partition and note it I assume it sda7 here.

mount /dev/sda7 /mnt  

mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/boot

grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda

mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

chroot /mnt update-grub

umount /mnt/sys

umount /mnt/dev

umount /mnt/proc

exit
```